# How to make QGIS model result to be a variable?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, qgis-variable

My model's temporary result is a point layer (one feature) and I need a value from one of its fields because I want to use it in the same model to select a feature on another layer.

So for example, after running the model, the result is a single point. This point has a field and its value is 46. I need this number in my model to select a feature on another layer (and I can carry on building the model).